# Creating a pattern list for text processing

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on a simple random poem generator program. I have wordlists for some models like: noun, adjective, verb etc. I implement them like this:

```
adjective = open('lexicon/adjective.txt')
noun = open('lexicon/noun.txt')
verb = open('lexicon/verb.txt')
```

The text files are in this format: `noun.txt`

```
tree
fish
computer
..
```

I'm using this function to select a random word from them:

```
def select_word(model):
    lines = model.read().splitlines()
    selectedline = random.choice(lines)
    return selectedline
```

I also have a pos tag list in this format (they are in my own language I just give English examples for better understanding):

```
went go[simplepast]
gone go[pastperfect]
..
```

I'm using this function to get first string before blank with given word and postag

```
def find_postag(word,postag):
    global selectedword
    zemberek = open('parse.txt')    
    for line in zemberek:
        if all(i in line for i in (word,postag)):
            selectedword = line.split(" ")[0]
            break
    return selectedword
```

**My idea is**: I need create a huge poem pattern list for putting random words into the suitable places in those pattern. For example let's say I have this sentence in my pattern list:

```
I was like a *noun*
```

Program should call `select_word(noun)` function (let's say it returned `"tree"`)and produce something like this:

```
I was like a tree
```

Let's say there is a postag definition after a word(sorry I couldn't find a suitable example in English):

```
I *verb*"[Past]" a friend of mine.
```

Now program should call `select_word(verb)` function to select a random word, let's say it returned `"host"` now It should call `find_postag("host","[Past]")` and it will return `"hosted"` Output should be:

```
I hosted a friend of mine.
```

**My problem is**: I'm not sure about the format of the pattern. The `*` and `"` chars are just for representation, I don't have to use them. I'm thinking about building pattern list in this format:

```
<pattern number=1 theme=heroic>
*noun* *nnoun* gibi
*nverb*"[Verb]+[Pos]+DH[Past]+m[A1sg]" deneme *adjective*"[Adj]-[Noun]+[A3sg]+Hm[P1sg]+[Nom] :"
</pattern>
<pattern number=2 theme=love>
(some other lines)
</pattern>
```

I tried to parse it like this:

```
def read_pattern(number,theme):
    pattern = open('poempatterns.txt').read().splitlines()
    for line in pattern:
        if line == "<pattern number="+number+" theme="+theme+">":
            while line != "</pattern>":
            #DO PARSING
```

What do you suggest about the format of the pattern list and how can I parse words and it's postag sepearately

Comment: If you are thinking about XML definitions you have to think about XML parsing too.

Answer (score -1):

If you have control over the structure of the data, I would suggest a more structured representation like JSON.

An example would be:

```
[{number: 1, theme: heroic, structure: [{type:"noun", modifier:["Past",..]},{..}]}]
```

There is a builtin json parser in python(`json.loads`) too.

P.S. I don't think:

```
if line == "<pattern number="+number+" theme="+theme+">":
```

would work.